# WebService request trascoding from Android code to Swift code

Tags: android, swift, web-services

I have this code in Android studio to call a WebService.
This is the code:

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = APIClient.loadInterface().signup(et_first_name.getText().toString(), et_last_name.getText().toString());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String responseData = response.body().string();
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(responseData);
                        if (object.optString("status").equals("1")) {
                            JSONObject userData = object.optJSONObject("result");
                            //decoding data

                        } 
                    }
                } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                   
                }
            }
```

With this code I m able to call a WebService and send also parameters.
Now I need to build the same method but in Swift. I m using the follow code but I receive "Nil Error":
This is the code:

```
var params = ["first_name" : "\(name)",
        "last_name" : "\(surname)",
        "type" : "user",
        "email" : "\(email)",
        "password" : "\(password)"]
        
        sendRequest("http://www.myxyzdomain.com/signup/", parameters: params) { responseObject, error in
            guard let responseObject = responseObject, error == nil else {
                print(error ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }
        }

func sendRequest(_ url: String, parameters: [String: String], completion: @escaping ([String: Any]?, Error?) -> Void) {
        var components = URLComponents(string: url)!
        components.queryItems = parameters.map { (key, value) in
            URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value)
        }
        components.percentEncodedQuery = components.percentEncodedQuery?.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%2B")
        let request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data,                            // is there data
                let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,  // is there HTTP response
                (200 ..< 300) ~= response.statusCode,         // is statusCode 2XX
                error == nil else {                           // was there no error, otherwise ...
                    completion(nil, error)
                    return
            }
            let responseObject = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any]
            completion(responseObject, nil)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

How can I trascoding correctly the Android code in swift code?

Comment: "Nil error"? What's nil? What are the values of your code. Is `completion(responseObject, nil)` called, or `ompletion(nil, error)`? Also, with `try?` you want to ignore error if you got data but failed to parse? In Swift you have params (which are more or less hidden in the Android code), it's unclear if you are sending the params correctly. Is the URL the same? Did you print it?

Comment: from Xcode utput console I receive "Unknown error", the URL is the same

Comment: But why? Because ` completion(responseObject, nil)` is called or because `completion(nil, error)` is called? Could you add intermerdiary prints or use breakpoints? You need to know which line of your code is called. If it's `responseObject` is nil, I'd do a property `do{try}catch {}`, not `try?`.

Comment: The is the line : "completion(nil, error)", error field is nil

Comment: Add `print("data: \(data)"); print("Response as HTTPURLResponse: \(response as? HTTPURLResponse)"), print("Error from Task: \(error)")`, give us the value. That's debugging,

Comment: where I can insert these line codes? In which point of my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231286/discussion-between-larme-and-bircastri).